# The nature of iterators, when used with vector<string> in C++

Tags: string, c++11, vector, iterator

I'm trying to put all of the command-line arguments into a `vector<string>` container. Here is what I have:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

   if (argc >= 2) {
       std::vector<std::string> words;
       for (auto itr = argv + 1; itr != argv+argc; ++itr) {
           words.push_back(*itr);
           std::cout<<"the word is : "<<words[**itr]<<std::endl;
       }
   } 
   else {
       std::cout<<"Error: Please enter a command-line argument!\n";
       return 0;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

While it compiles just fine (GCC 5.3.0) the output is blank:

```
MacBook-Pro:trial2 Hossein$ ./main.exe Hello, my name is Hossein

the word is : 
the word is : 
the word is : 
the word is : 
the word is :
```

Intuitively, I would have used `words[itr]` inside the loop. Why is that wrong? From a more general perspective, what is the nature of `itr` here? In other words, how would you replace `auto` with `vector::iterator` in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, `auto` resolves to a `char**` pointer, where `*itr` accesses a particular string in the `argv[]` array, and `**itr` accesses the first character of that string. That is not a valid index into the `vector` elements.

`<< words[**itr]` should be simply `<< *itr` instead.

If you really want to use `vector` iterators, you should do the `push_back()` loop by itself first, and then used a second loop to iterate the completed vector afterwards, eg:

```
for (auto itr = argv + 1; itr != argv+argc; ++itr) {
    words.push_back(*itr);
}

for (auto &word : words) {
    std::cout << "the word is : " << word << std::endl;
}
```

In which case, the first loop can be replaced with `std::copy()` and `std::back_inserter`, eg:

```
std::copy(argv + 1, argv + argc, std::back_inserter(words));

for (auto &w : words) {
    std::cout << "the word is : " << w << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: remind that this will copy only the pointer values, not the strings. shall the strings be deleted elsewhere, all these pointers are invalidated.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira: The `words` vector is declared as holding `std::string` values, so pushing the `char*` pointers will construct `std::string` objects that copy the character data, and then `auto &w` would be `std::string &w`. What you say is true only if the vector were declared to hold `char*` pointers instead. Besides, the `argv[]` array is not freed until `main()` exits, and the vector gets freed before then, so even if it did hold just pointers, the pointers would remain valid for the lifetime of the vector (unless it is declared in global memory).

Comment: Whoopsie, my bad. I didn't notice that it is a vector of std::string

Comment: Also, even tho argv isn't freed until the program is terminated, it is good to remind that, for other objects, it might happen early.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that instead

```
std::cout<<"the word is : "<<words[**itr]<<std::endl;
```

you should write

```
std::cout<<"the word is : "<< words.back() <<std::endl;
```

if your intention is show the last string inserted in `words`

I'm surprised that `words[**itr]` didn't kill the program because, with "Hello, my name is Hossein", the `**itr` values are the first char of the words, that is "`H`" (integer 72), "`m`" (integer 109), "`n`" (integer 110), "`i`" (integer 105) and again "`H`".

So with `words[**itr]` you should access in position too higth for `words`.

The OP ask

> I'm wondering if there is a way to have random access with [] operator?

Yes, there is:

```
   for (auto i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
       words.push_back(argv[i]);
       std::cout << "the word is : " << words[i-1] << std::endl;
   }
```

But I think (IMHO) that with `back()` is more elegant.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I'm wondering if there is a way to have random access with `[] operator`?

Comment: @em.ech - answer improved.

Comment: in your suggested code for random access I believe `auto` is simply equivalent to `int`, which is fine! But I'm trying to understand what the compiler is doing with `auto` when I use iterators for `vector<string>` and why `words[ itr ]` is wrong?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your response. If you write it as an answer I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @em.ech: I have posted an answer.